# C# ASP.NET Core MongoDB "Method not found: 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionSettings"

Tags: c#, mongodb, blazor

I am receiving the following error when trying to insert an item asynchronously:

```
[2020-10-05T09:17:13.144Z] Error: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'BlazorApp3.Database.MongoContext' threw an exception. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionSettings MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionSettings.With(MongoDB.Driver.Optional`1<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.IAuthenticator>>, MongoDB.Driver.Optional`1<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.CompressorConfiguration>>, MongoDB.Driver.Optional`1<System.TimeSpan>, MongoDB.Driver.Optional`1<System.TimeSpan>, MongoDB.Driver.Optional`1<System.String>)'
```

Here is where I am inserting:

```
public async Task Insert()
    {
        await MongoContext.GetCollection<Clock>().InsertOneAsync(this);
    }
```

Here is where I am calling the Insert method from my Razor page:

```
async Task InsertNewClock()
{
    Clock clock = new Clock(DateTime, "Username");

    await clock.Insert();
}
```

And finally, my MongoContext class where the static MongoClient is:

```
public class MongoContext
{
    private static readonly MongoClient _Client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    private const String _DatabaseName = "BlazorApplicationTesting";

    public static IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>(String databaseName = _DatabaseName)
    {
        return _Client.GetDatabase(databaseName).GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

I am really stuck here, I'm sure I've used this method of using Mongo before and this is the first time I'm receiving this error.

Comment: Blazor Server or Blazor Wasm?

Comment: I'm using Blazor Server